# Google Maps geolocation API store on .click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I am fairly new to Google Maps API and not very experienced in JS. I've got some questions on geolocations. What I am trying to achieve: a user's current geolocation should be **saved** onclick, **displayed** on map and **stored on clientside**, so that it can be navigated to in later steps. The code below in its current state shows the geolocation of a user in an *(InfoWindow)* as the map is rendered for the first time.

Any hints on how to achieve what I am planning to do?

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 18
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Geolocation in HTML
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('You are here!');
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

Comment: K, slightly confused with your question. You want the map saved after a button is clicked locally? Or on the server?

Comment: Drop a marker to display the location and store those coordinates in localStorage or a cookie?  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp